# AngularJs Service called from two places returns same value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I am new to angular and pardon my ignorance if any. I am trying to create a simple service that will do a get funtionality and serve data into array. 
The problem i am having is, no mattter what i do - i always get the same data for any parameter i pass.

Here is my sample service

```
function myService($http, $q) {
    var service = {
        getSomeData: getSomeData:

    };
    var def = $q.defer();

    return service;

    function getSomeData(category) {


        if (category === 'books') {
            url = 'http://www.someurl1';
        } else {
            url = 'http://www.someurl2'
        };

        $http.get(url, {
            params: {
                'type': category
            }

        }).success(function(data) {
            def.resolve(data);
        }).error(function() {
            def.reject('Failed to get data');
        });
        return def.promise;
    }
}

})();
```

Once i have this, in my controller, i am trying to call it for sample purposes like this

```
$scope.someData = [] ;
$scope.someData.push(myService.getSomeData('DVDs'); 
$scope.someData.push(myService.getSomeData('books');
```

Now when i my look at my $scope.someData, 
i have an array of two objects - the problem being that they are always the same and doesnt have data specific to books and dvds.

Another minor issue I have is my object someData has

> array --> Promise -- > $$state --> value

which then has the actual data. how can i get the data directly. 
i tried return `def.promise(data);`

Comment: as i can see, you have `books` in service `if` statement, but passing Books to service function calling. Check your params case

Comment: @SergioIvanuzzo that is just a typo when i pasted here.. let me correct that

Comment: not related to your actual question, but your code violates a couple very key angular principles here.  First, the use of `defer` unnecesssarily (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it), second, the use of `.success` (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35329384/why-are-angular-http-success-error-methods-deprecated-removed-from-v1-6).  You may want to consider refactoring your code.

Comment: Thanks @Claies for the feedback.. i knew i might be not doing it the right way since i was picking pieces from different examples.. i followed what charlietfl solution.. works like a charm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One problem is you are only creating one promise outside the `getSomeData` function.

A promise can only be resolved once. You need a new promise for each request.

Also `$http` already returns a promise but you can't push it directly into an array as data.

your code should look more like:

Service:

```
function myService($http, $q) {
  var service = {
    getSomeData: getSomeData
  };


  return service;

  function getSomeData(category) {

    if (category === 'books') {
      url = 'http://www.someurl1';
    } else {
      url = 'http://www.someurl2'
    };

    return $http.get(url, {
      params: {
        'type': category
      }
    }).then(function(response) {
      return response.data;
    }).catch(function(err) {
      console.log("Ooops", err)
    });
  }
}
```

Controller

```
$scope.someData = [] ;
myService.getSomeData('DVDs').then(function(data){
   data.forEach(function(item){
       $scope.someData.push(item);
   });
});
```